# C# Gridview - Set header row tooltip programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, header-row

I have a gridview which has 2 header rows as below

```
| Name  |   Subject1  |  Subject2   |
|       |  T  |  V    |  T  |  V    |
|-------|-----|-------|-----|-------|
| John  |  80 | 20    | 78  |  18   |
| Ann   |  75 | 18    | 68  |  15   |
```

The grid view data source is a data table which i have created dynamically. Header rows are also created dynamically. 
Now I want to set tooltip for the second header row as 'Theory' for 'T' and 'Viva' for 'V'.

By using gvMarks.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Tooltip, I am able to set tooltip only for the first header row. 
If I use gvMarks.Rows[1].Cells[1].Tooltip, I am able to access only the grid data rows.

How can I access the second header row so that I can set the tooltip programatically.

Comment: Where this `GridView` from: WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: grid view is in asp.net . i am creating the data table dynamically and setting it as the gridview data source. Second header row also creating dynamically.